# Count the records in a "where" statment and saves them in a VB.NET Label

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm developing software in VB.NET that is linked to a MySQL database. In my software, the user will be allowed to search (for example: Model of Desktop = MKV5000), and then navigate throughout the search query in a form using 4 buttons.

What I want to do is count the total number of records that the search has returned and then show them in a label along side the number of the record that is currently being shown.

Can anyone please help me?

Sorry in advance for any language and/or expressions mistakes.

Comment: both the query and the control (such as a datagridview) used to display the results can tell you how many.

Comment: Yes i know, the problem is that i can not use a datagridview,  it has to be in-Form because i have to use a groupBox and a bunch of checkBoxe's...

Comment: well, the number of records ought to be the same as the number of checkboxes you create

Comment: No,  the checkboxe's is for data imput and output, to save values in the DB and to show them in the VB software...

Comment: In the software, the checkBox represents parts of a computer,  such as CPU, GPU , Display, etc...

That is why i can't use a DataGridView..

Comment: You want to show the user Result #1, Result #2, etc... Correct? And you want to navigate the recordset using 4 buttons? First, Next, Previous, Last? Why not use binding navigator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/how-to-bind-bindingnavigator-with-datagridview/

Comment: That is already done!  
What i want to do is Count the number of records and show them in a label aloungside with the number of the record that is currently being shown...

Comment: the binding navigator shows the number of the current record. You will just need to code the changes to your form. I feel like your approach is a bit off. Why would you want to show the number from the recordset and not a unique ID (part number) for the item? The recordset item number is useless.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/working-with-bindingnavigator-control/

you can try to pass the record number to a text box if the location of the number is not adequate.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that i'm using a mysql table on XAMPP,  i can't use the binding navigator...

Comment: that may have been important to note in the begining.  Can you share your code for the select, and for navigation?

Comment: For the Select:

    strsql = "select * from componentes where marca= '" & T_marca.Text & "';"
                    comando.CommandText = strsql
                    r1 = comando.ExecuteReader
                    bg.DataSource = r1

 



For the navigation: 


    carregar()
            bg.MoveFirst()

            t_processo.Text = bg.Current(1)
            C_tipo.Text = bg.Current(2)
            T_marca.Text = bg.Current(3)

            T_modelo.Text = bg.Current(4)

            If bg.Current(5) = 1 Then
                c_Display.Checked = True

Comment: Show the full method, not just these selection. What is bg?

Comment: bg its the binding source

Comment: @user3360347 - Please don't put blocks of code in a comment.  Edit your original question and add the code there, using the proper formatting.  What you have posted in the comment is almost unreadable.